# Python sublist for a condition

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists `x`, `y`, `z` and I plot them with:

```
ax.plot3D(x, y, z, linestyle = 'None', marker = 'o').
```

What is the easiest way to only plot the points where `x > 0.5`?

(my problem is how to define a sublist under a condition without making a for loop on that list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to verify a condition on every element of a list without iterating over it at least once. You could use numpy here for easy access to the elements after condition is passsed and do:

```
 import numpy
 x = [0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]
 y = [0.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.6]
 z = [0.0, 9.1, 1.0, 0.9]
 res = numpy.array([[x[i], y[i], z[i]] for i in xrange(len(x)) if x[i] > 0.5])
 ax.plot3D(res[:,0], res[:,1], res[:,2], linestyle="None, marker='o'")
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you're avoiding looping over a list and I'm assuming that you want the related points in the other lists also removing.

```
>>> x = [0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]
>>> y = [0.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.6]
>>> z = [0.0, 9.1, 1.0, 0.9]
>>> zip(x,y,z)
[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.4, 2.2, 9.1), (0.6, 1.5, 1.0), (1.0, 1.6, 0.9)]
>>> [item for item in zip(x,y,z) if item[0] > 0.5]
[(0.6, 1.5, 1.0), (1.0, 1.6, 0.9)]
```

Separating the list into it's constituent lists will require looping over the list somehow.

Comment: Separating the list back into the individual lists can be done with another call to zip: `f = [item for item in zip(x,y,z) if item[0] > 0.5]; zip(*f)`

Comment: @lvc I like that! You should add that as an answer and it should be accepted!

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehension won't be enough to remove the (x,y,z) tuples if x <= 0.5, you'll have to do a little more, I use [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) for the second part :

```
from operator import itemgetter

result = [(a, b, c) for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z) if a > 0.5] # first, remove the triplet
x = itemgetter(0)(result)  # then grab from the new list the x,y,z parts
y = itemgetter(1)(result)
z = itemgetter(2)(result)

ax.plot3D(x, y, z, linestyle="None, marker='o')
```

**EDIT:** 
Following and upgrading @shenshei advice we can achieve it with a one-line:

```
ax.plot3D(
  *zip(*[(a, b, c) for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z) if a > 0.5]), 
  linestyle="None, 
  marker='o'
)
```

Comment: you could also do `x, y, z = zip(*result)`

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `x = [itemgetter(0)(point) for point in result]`?

Comment: @shenshei : I take your remark, and I used it into a one-liner :)

Answer (score 2):

Reposting my comment as an answer as suggested by @StephenPaulger . You can do this with a generator expression and a couple of calls to the built-in `zip()`:

```
x = [0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]
y = [0.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.6]
z = [0.0, 9.1, 1.0, 0.9]

points = (point for point in zip(x, y, z) if point[0] > 0.5)
x, y, z = zip(*points)
```

You could also use a list comprehension for `points` if you want to, but - assuming Python 3, where `zip()` no longer precomputes a full list when called - that might hurt your memory usage and speed, especially if the number of points is large.

Answer (score 2):

Probably using `numpy` would provide the cleanest approach. However, you will need to have lists/arrays `x`, `y`, and `z` as `numpy` arrays. So, first convert these lists to numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
z = np.asarray(z)
```

Now compute an array of indices of elements that satisfy your condition:

```
idx = np.where(x > 0.5)
```

NOTE: Alternatively, you could compute a boolean mask: `idx=x>0.5` (this will not change the use of `idx` in the next `ax.plot3D` statement).

Use these indices to select only those specific points in `x`, `y`, and `z` that satisfy desired condition:

```
ax.plot3D(x[idx], y[idx], z[idx], linestyle = 'None', marker = 'o')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to steal lvc's thunder, but here's a variant on their answer:

```
>>> x = [0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9]
>>> y = [0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8]
>>> z = [0.9, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3]
>>> 
>>> a, b, c = zip(*filter(lambda t: t[0] > 0.5, zip(x, y, z)))
>>> print a, "\n", b, "\n", c
(0.6, 0.8, 0.9) 
(0.1, 0.5, 0.8) 
(0.2, 0.4, 0.3)
>>> ax.plot3D(a, b, c, linestyle = 'None', marker = 'o')
```